# Controllers not called anymore after upgrading from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to 2.2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I updated a simple ASP.NET Core project from 2.0 to 2.2, updating references. This project (only) uses MVC controllers with `Route` attributes.

After the update, routes are never found. All HTTP requests end up with 404.

I tested many combinations of `.SetCompatibilityVersion(...)`, without any luck. From what I could read about such an update, I did not expect any other changes to be required.

I tried to compare with a new "webapi" project. The only differences I see is the absence of `UseHsts()` and `UseHttpsRedirection` in Startup, no `[ApiController]` attribute on controllers, and controllers deriving from `Controller` instead of its base `ControllerBase`. I don't see how this explains why controllers are not called, and would have expected all this to work "as is".

A controller:

```cs
    [Route("/")]
    public class RootController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public RootController(ILogger<RootController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Ping received!");
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
```

The Startup:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Unrelated stuff

            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            // More unrelated stuff
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Where should I look at?

**EDIT**: The `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` was actually changed from 2.0.7 (with a 2.1 target framework) to no version (with a 2.2 target framework) in the project. When compiling and running with 2.0, controllers get called.

Comment: Add your route configuration code and a sample controller code.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with routing in 2.2 related to bugs in the new EndpointRouting feature. The issues will be fixed in 3.0  but in 2.2 you can workaround by disable the new feature which is not needed.

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;

        });
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested this, with and without `SetCompatibilityVersion` (any version), but I still have the same issue. Do you have pointers on these related bugs?

Comment: Source or Github issue would be nice.